# css=div.clasname seems not working in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I try in several elements to use click element css=div.classname and is not working. I use robot framework with Python 2.7. and Selenium 2 Library
here is one of my elements:

It is a Radio button that I want to select:

```
 span class="docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel" dir="auto">Prevention</span>
```

and my Robotframework code that is not working is:

```
Click correct answer
    click element    css=div.ocssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel
```

I appreciate everyone's help.

He is the image and how the radio button is inside a scrollable frame

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Are you limited to using the css=* selector? Have you tried other selector such as xpath?

Comment: When I say is not working I mean that Robotframework doesn't do the selection of the element. In the log file states that cannot find it.  I have used others beside CSS and work fine. Specially if I use the id as selection. I haven't so far able to make it with CSS=DIV.CLASS or use the name as selector. I wondered if it is a version issue.

Comment: I tried another way but still no luck. I used Xpath checker with Firefox browser to get the XPath for the Radio button.  I used this command to select it.  Selenium2Library.click element   xpath=id('mG61Hd')/x:div/x:div[2]/x:div[2]/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:div/x:content/x:div/x:label[3]/x:div/x:div[2]/x:div/x:span    I get at the log the error message  Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression id('mG61Hd')/x:div/...etc because of the following error: Error: Namespace prefix not declared: x   Xpath checker has  namespace x. So I do not understand why it says not declared!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Solve:

```
Click correct answer
    click element           sizzle=.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText
```

Comment: I get Javascript error. I use Selenium2 Library. is there any other library I need to add?  Here is the Log      12:17:58.999
INFO
Clicking element 'sizzle=.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText'.
12:17:59.477
FAIL
WebDriverException: Message: JavaScript error

Comment: how many class=.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText in your page ? Could you inspect using console and type $(".docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText").length

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use the console and I got Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference    . However I used the Dom explorer and I found that for each radio button on my page i I have a match,  So i have at least 25 matches. You can check the page yourself if you like . https://sites.google.com/site/softwareqaacademy/home/entity-1--introduction/introduction/quiz-1--qa-vs-test       Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer:

```
Selenium2Library.Select Frame   xpath=//iframe[@title="QUIZ : QA VS TEST"]
Selenium2Library.click element  xpath = //div[contains(@class, "ItemHeader") and descendant::div[text()="What describes best Quality assurance "]]/..//div[@data-value="Prevention"]
```

- First command selects the Iframe using the Xpath
- Second command selects the Radio button using the Xpath

Answer (score -1):

you use div.class class. I see 2 problems:

1. it's span, not div
2. to use selector by 2 classes use:

   .class.class

so, please try this one:

```
click element    css=span.ocssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel
```

Comment: why is this answer any better than what they are doing? Your answer would be better if you explained what you changed, otherwise the reader is left to compare your answer to the question one character at a time.

Comment: It didn't work. I attach a printscreen above to see where is the Radio button. Basically is inside a scrollable frame.

Comment: this is from log file 12:13:30.119
INFO
Clicking element 'css=div.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel'.

12:13:30.842
FAIL
ValueError: Element locator 'css=div.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel' did not match any elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but still doesn't work. Cannot find the element. I even try to make it wait to ensure the Element is visible but not luck.  Here is the log  KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Wait Until Element Is Visible ss=span.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel  Documentation:  Waits until element specified with `locator` is visible. Start / End / Elapsed:
13:39:45.494  FAIL  Element locator  css=span.docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel' did not match any elements after 5 seconds